# Determinant of a block rectangular matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Assume that $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}, b \in \mathbb{R}, P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, u \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}, x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now I want to compute the eigenvalues of matrix $A$ where

\begin{equation}
A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} && -a-Pu && -\lambda P\\
(a+Pu)^\top && 0_{1 \times 1} && x^\top P \\
\lambda P^\top && P^\top x && 0_{n \times n}
\end{array} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{(2n+1) \times (2n+1)}.
\end{equation}

We have

\begin{equation}
det (A-s I_{(2n+1) \times (2n+1)})=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-sI_{n}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} && -a-Pu && -\lambda P\\
(a+Pu)^\top && -s && x^\top P \\
\lambda P^\top && P^\top x && -s I_{n}
\end{array} \right)=0.
\end{equation}

What is the best way to proceed? I wanna simplify this determinant such that I can obtain a solution for the eigenvalues. Would appreciate any help...